# $x$ is orthogonal to $y$ iff $\|x+ay\| \geq \|x\|$ where $x \in C$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Show that in an inner product space,
$x$ is orthogonal to $y$ iff $\|x+ay\| \geq \|x\|$ where $x \in C$.

Proof:

**LHS:** If $x$ is orthogonal to $y$, then $\langle x,y\rangle =0$. Let $a \in \mathbb C$.

$\|x+ay\|^2 = \langle x+ay,x+ay\rangle =\langle x,x\rangle +\langle ay,ay\rangle +\langle x,ay\rangle +\langle ay,x\rangle $ $\geq \langle x,x\rangle =\|x\|^2$

Hence $\|x+ay\| \geq \|x\|$.

**RHS:** If $\|x+ay\| \geq \|x\|$ for $a \in \mathbb C$, then

$\|x+ay\|^2 = \langle x+ay,x+ay\rangle =\langle x,x\rangle +\langle ay,ay\rangle +\langle x,ay\rangle +\langle ay,x\rangle = 1 + \bar{a}\langle x,y\rangle +a\langle y,x\rangle =1 + \bar{a}\bar{\langle y,x\rangle }+a\langle y,x\rangle $

But I don't know how to continue. Can someone guide me to finish this proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that, for any $a\in\mathbb C$, 
$$
\|x\|\leq\|x+ay\|=\|x\|+2\,\text{Re}\,a\langle y,x\rangle,
$$
or
$$
2\,\text{Re}\,a\langle y,x\rangle\geq0.
$$
In particular this would hold for $a_0=-\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$, so 
$$
-2|\langle y,x\rangle|^2=2\,\text{Re}\,a_0\langle y,x\rangle\geq0.
$$
The only way this can happen is when $\langle y,x\rangle =0$.